# Send the value input type text to another php file using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, paypal

I'm trying to send the value of this

```
<form class="paypal" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="business" value="nineteenseventees@gmail.com">
      <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
      <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
      <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="'.$fetch['ShirtType'].'-'.$fetch['ShirtSize'].'-'.$fetch['ShirtColor'].'">
      <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="'.$fetch['itemnum'].'">
      <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="'.$fetch['quantity'].'">
      <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="'.$fetch['ItemPrice'].'">
      <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="PHP">
      <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://localhost/imageupload/index.php">
      <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://localhost/imageupload/paysuccess.php">
      <input type="hidden" id="ordernumber" value="'.$fetch['OrderNum'].'">
      <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit" id="paypalbutton" name="paypalbutton"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
```

When I press the button, this go to paypal. But I want it to go to paypal via ajax and also save the OrderNum to session.

I tried using AJAX but i can't seem to make it work. here it is

```
  $('#paypalbutton').on('click', function(e){
  var num = $("#ordernumber").val();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'redirect.php',
    data: {
        onumber: num
    }
 }); 
});
```

I'm trying to send it here: **redirect.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'dbconnect.php';

$_SESSION['order'] = $_POST['onumber'];
echo $_SESSION['order'];

?>
```

Comment: Starting a session and populating the session in a remote file will not cause the local file to get the session data until refreshed.

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: Yes. The jQuery library is included and there are no errors reported. I'm running this on localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.paypal').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var num = $("#ordernumber").val();
    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'redirect.php',
       data: {
          onumber: num
       }
   }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**First of All:**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="button" id="paypalbutton" name="paypalbutton"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
```

**Second:**

```
      $('#paypalbutton').click(function(){
         var num = $("#ordernumber").val();
         $.post('redirect.php',{onumber:num},function(data){
           if(data){
              console.log(data);
              $(".paypal").submit();
           }

         }); 
      });
```

Replace this by your javascript code please and try once.